# Activity not running its onCreate code

Tags: java, android-activity

EDIT: I just noticed I have this error, could someone identify which object is not specified? I can provide anything else if needed:

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
>
> W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4226)
>   W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
>   W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
>   W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
>   W/System.err:     at com.dividedbyzerostudios.candycrawler.GameplayScene.update(GameplayScene.java:153)
>   W/System.err:     at com.dividedbyzerostudios.candycrawler.SceneManager.update(SceneManager.java:29)
>   W/System.err:     at com.dividedbyzerostudios.candycrawler.GamePanel.update(GamePanel.java:81)
>   W/System.err:     at com.dividedbyzerostudios.candycrawler.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:44)

---

I am using a scene manager in my game, with the game itself being one scene and the results being another. The scene manager is this:

```
public class SceneManager {
private ArrayList<Scene> scenes = new ArrayList<>();
public static int ACTIVE_SCENE;

public SceneManager() {
    ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
    scenes.add(new GameplayScene());
    scenes.add(new result());
}


public void recieveTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    scenes.get(ACTIVE_SCENE).recieveTouch(event);
}

public void update() {
    scenes.get(ACTIVE_SCENE).update();
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    scenes.get(ACTIVE_SCENE).draw(canvas);
}
}
```

Where each Scene implements the scene class:

```
public interface Scene {
public void update();
public void draw(Canvas canvas);
public void terminate();
public void recieveTouch(MotionEvent event);
}
```

The gameplay scene works fine, however when I switch the ACTIVE_SCENE to 1 (when the game ends) and give an intent to run the result activity (below) it ignores the onCreate method in the result activity (see after):

```
public class result extends AppCompatActivity implements Scene {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { /*This is being ignored*/
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    TextView scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreLabel);
    TextView highScoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highScoreLabel);

    int score = Constants.SCORE;
    scoreLabel.setText(score + "");

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = settings.getInt("HIGH_SCORE", 0);

    if(score > highScore) {
        highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " + score);

        //save
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("HIGH_SCORE", score);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " + highScore);
    }
}

public void tryAgain() { /*How I plan to change back to the game*/
    SceneManager.ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
}

public void update() {

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

}

public void terminate() {

}

public void recieveTouch(MotionEvent event) {

}
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the activity and changing the scene:

```
public class GameplayScene extends Activity implements Scene {

@Override
public void update() {

    if(gameOver) {
        //
        SceneManager.ACTIVE_SCENE = 1; //changing the scene
        Intent intent = new Intent(CURRENT_CONTEXT, result.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCORE", Constants.SCORE);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I've tried not making the result page a scene and trying to just run it from the intent, however it just causes the end of the game to freeze. 
Currently it appears that it is running all the code in the result class apart from the onCreate.

Comment: Please, make sure you understand the Activity lifecycle. onCreate you only called if the activity wasn't created before or it the OS killed its process before you invoking it again. Please, check https://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png

Comment: `scenes.add(new result());`... Never *ever* make a `new` Activity. Since you did, then yes, `onCreate` is never ran.

Comment: @cricket_007 So is there any way I can use the result activity with my scene manager? If so how would I do that correctly?

Comment: You can have a Scene class, but don't treat an Activity as a Scene that you can simply create as a regular Java object

Comment: If you want to pass results between Activities, Intent is one option, or you can make your SceneManager class a singleton object